# What is the best way of instantiating many JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, performance

I need to create many instances of a specific class in a single page, and I'm wondering if the way that I define the methods of that class will have an impact on the page's performance.  Does it matter whether I define the methods like this:

```
function Foo(h, l) {
  this.h = h;
  this.l = l;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function(x) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or this:

```
function Foo(h, l) { 
  this.h = h;
  this.l = l;

  this.bar = function(x) {
    // do stuff
  };
}
```

Does one offer performance benefits over the other if I have to create many instances of this class (and if the class has several other methods)?  Or is there another, better way I should be using?  Assume that I instantiate all of the objects using `new Foo(h,l);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is much preferred. In that case, there is only one definition of the `bar` function, and all `Foo` objects share it. In the second case, the `bar` function is being declared every single time, and each object contains their own version of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the first method as the same `bar` property is shared by every `Foo` instance.